# What is path in android update project --path command

Tags: android, linux, tesseract

I am making an Android OCR App using Tesseract following http://www.kaustubhraghavan.com/ocr.html tutorials. What is path in android update project --path . command (on ubuntu)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`android update project` is a *very* old approach. I strongly recommend that you find some newer information on how to use this library, ideally something written within the past 1-2 years.

That being said `--path` is a command-line switch. It indicates where to find your project. In your sample command (`android update project --path .`), the value you are giving for the `--path` switch is `.`, indicating that the project is in the current working directory.

Comment: so where should I set the path ( or current directory)? as it is saying ". is not a valid project (AndroidManifest.xml not found)."

Comment: @abhimanyubishnoi: Either replace `.` with a path to your project, or use `cd` to change to the project directory (so `.` points to your project).

Comment: @abhimanyubishnoi: Let me emphasize: **I strongly recommend that you find some newer information on how to use this library**. For example, a search for `tess-two "android studio"` on Google turns up [this](https://coderwall.com/p/eurvaq/tesseract-with-andoird-and-gradle) and [this](http://androidadvance.com/blog/tutorial-getting-started-with-tessaract-ocr-in-android-android-studio/) and [this](https://priyankvex.wordpress.com/2015/08/30/how-to-build-tesseract-ocr-library-for-android-studio/).

Comment: @abhimanyubishnoi It's easiest to include the library by editing your `build.gradle` file: See [here](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two#usage).